# How do I get more than one result at a time from a FAST ESP query

Tags: fast-esp

I'm currently using the java fast esp interface (v5.0.15.1) to query fast and retrieve results.  However I can only seem to get a document iterator from the IQueryResult and each call to .next() seems to be a http request.  Is there a better way to deal with bulk results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The api should be retrieving multiple results at a time, though next will periodically issue queries to populate the iterator.  The number of queries fetched in each chunk is determined by the HITS parameter... so make sure it's higher than 1... default is normally 10 I think.

You can check the query logs $FASTSEARCH/var/log/querylogs to see what the api is currently passing for the hits param.

Have fun.

Comment: Yep, this works great.  I noticed while debugging that it does fetch in batches of 10 by default, not 1 like I thought.